# Wrong value assigned to variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, user-defined-functions

I've started drafting a scalar function in SSMS 2012 to take a string and swap any occurrence of 3 hex URL characters (`%2b`, `%2f` and `%3d`) with their respective single character (`-`, `/` and `=`):

```
DECLARE @OutputText as VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @c as Int   
DECLARE @cIn as CHAR(3)
DECLARE @cOut as CHAR(1)
DECLARE @s as Int

SET     @OutputText = '%2bBWCq6sE7OU%3d'
SET     @c = 1

WHILE @c <= 3
    BEGIN
        -- Set the search/replace characters depending on iteration
        IF  @c = 1
            SET @cIn = '%2b'
            SET @cOut = '-';
        IF  @c = 2
            SET @cIn = '%2f'
            SET @cOut = '/';
        IF  @c = 3
            SET @cIn = '%3d'
            SET @cOut = '=';

        SET @s = PATINDEX('%' + @cIn +'%', @OutputText)

        WHILE @s > 0
            BEGIN

                PRINT 'Character Loop: ' + CAST(@c as VARCHAR(1)) + ' | looking for ' + @cIn + ' within ' + @OutputText
                PRINT '(Replace ' + @cIn + ' with ' + @cOut + ')'
                PRINT '-- ' + @cIn + ' found at position: ' + CAST(@s as VARCHAR(2))

                SET @OutputText = STUFF(@OutputText, PATINDEX('%' + @cIn +'%', @OutputText) - 1, 3, @cOut)

                PRINT '>> OutputText now: ' + @OutputText + CHAR(10)

                SET @s = PATINDEX('%' + @cIn +'%', @OutputText)

            END

    SET     @c = @c + 1

    END

PRINT 'Final output: ' + @OutputText
```

The various `PRINT`s return this:

[image]

Notice the first character loop output says `Replace %2b with =` ... yet the `if` statement should be setting `@cOut` to `-` not `=` when `@c = 1`.

Another minor issue is that where the output says `%2b found at position:` the position number given seems 1 higher than it should be, like it's ignoring `%` of `@cIn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your If statements, each setting of @cout will happen because they are not part of the IF.  Only the next line after the IF executes.  You need to wrap them in Begin End:

```
IF  @c = 1
begin
    SET @cIn = '%2b'
    SET @cOut = '-'
end
else IF  @c = 2
begin
    SET @cIn = '%2f'
    SET @cOut = '/'
end
else IF  @c = 3
begin
    SET @cIn = '%3d'
    SET @cOut = '='
end
```

To prove this:

```
declare @thing int = 2

if @thing=1
select 'ralph'
select 'charles'

if @thing = 2
select 'ralph2'
select 'charles2'
```

This will produce charles, ralph2, charles2

Whereas this (with begin end):

```
declare @thing int = 2

if @thing=1
begin
    select 'ralph'
    select 'charles'
end

if @thing = 2
begin
    select 'ralph2'
    select 'charles2'
end
```

will correctly produce ralph2, charles2

Comment: ahh ok, I though `;` would break them up. Thanks for helping :)